# Is it possible to search multiple criteria's in imaplib

Tags: python-3.x, imaplib

I succesfully created a script that searches mail from a specific sender (FROM) and perform actions with it. The only problem I have atm is that it loops through all mail from that sender. (it's an automatic mail that sends every hour), so after a few days, it takes a while to loop through everything.

My question now is the following:

Is it possible to search for multiple criterias? And if so how can i search for unseen?
I was thinking something like this:

```
fb, data = con.search(None, 'FROM', "***@coatings.com", '(UNSEEN)')
```

But no succes...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: put all in single bracket '(FROM "***@coatings.com"  UNSEEN)'

Comment: For more info refer http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3501.html